# How to set Location Bias in the new places Autocomplete for Android?

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places

I'm migrating to the new New Places SDK Client in my android app. I'm trying not to use the compatibility library, but rather use all the new objects.
The only feature I use from the SDK is the builtin Autocomplete activity.

I managed to create the `Autocomplete.IntentBuilder` and I see that it has a `setLocationBias()` method just like the previous `PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder`.

However this method takes as a parameter an interface `LocationBias` that only extends `Parcelable` and has no members of its own so I'm not sure how to implement it, or how to mention the location that I need in it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LocationBias takes RectangularBounds.
you need to create two LatLng objects with north east & south west coordinates for the bounds and instantiate the RectangularBounds object with them:

```
val northEast = LatLng(double, double)
val southWest = LatLng(double, double)
```

and pass it to:

```
RectangularBounds.newInstance(southWest, northEast);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment since my reputation is still under 50.

Just wanted to address a correction of the voted answer as RectangularBounds takes southWest argument first then the northEast argument, as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/places/api/model/RectangularBounds#public-static-rectangularbounds-newinstance-latlng-southwest,-latlng-northeast).

So the right way would be

```
RectangularBounds.newInstance(southWest, northEast);
```

Doing the opposite would result in an exception error.